# Graph with answer box

Tags: plotting, graphics

I use this Plot to generate the graphs of `Sen[x], Cos[x] and Tan[x]`:

```
Plot[{Sin[x],Cos[x],Tan[x]},{x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotRange->{-4,4},ImageSize->Large]
```

I would like to put, on the right, 3 text box with questions like "Which is the color of the Sen function?" and 3 empty box where a student can write his answer to the question.

I would like also to check the answers.

How can I do something similar to that?

Comment: See Labeled and InputField.

Comment: @Lotus can you help me using them in the way I mean?

Comment: What do you mean when you say check the answers ?

Comment: If the answer of "What function is the red one?" is wrong ,  I would like to highlight to the user that he has answered bad.
Now I am watching the PopMenu[] item.

Comment: This is a start: list = {InputField["", String, 
   FieldHint -> "Color of Sine Function"],
  InputField["", String, FieldHint -> "Color of Cosine Function"],
  InputField["", String, FieldHint -> "Color of Tan Function"]} and Labeled[Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Tan[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {-4, 4}, ImageSize -> Large], Column[list], Right]. You can create a similar column for your comments as "Correct", "Wrong" etc..

Comment: If you want Dynamic evaluation of the answers you can have something similar to {InputField[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[If[x == 5, "Correct", "Incorrect"]]}